# Function call doesnt work python

Tags: python

Im trying to print palindrome words in a file (where each line is a word) in python.
Thats what I have so far:
I have to work in Unix so I wrote my script in file palindrome.py as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def isPalindrome(a):
    if a == a[::-1]:
        print a

with open ('fileName') as f:
   for line in f:
       isPalindrome(line)
```

When I run the file it doesn't print anything even-though there are palindrome words in my file. I think the problem is related to my function call because if instead of `isPalindrome(line)` I have `isPalindrome('aha')` it will print `aha`. I tried to print each line after the for loop but that works as well. It does print all the lines of the file. So line does get different values so I guess there might be something related to the call but I am failing to find out what.

Answer (score 6):

You need to strip newlines from the end of your lines. Try call as `isPalindrome(line.strip())`.

Comment: Might also be useful to ignore case differences.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Attention: `file.readlines()` **does not wrap** end line characters!!

so if in you file you have `aha` in one line, the line will be `aha\n` (with the new line char...)...

I suggest use of `replace()` string method.

Your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def isPalindrome(a):
    if a == a[::-1]:
        print a

with open ('fileName') as f:
   for line in f:
       isPalindrome(line.replace('\n', '').replace("\r", "")) # replace carriage return / line feed chars
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked with the file.readlines()  as well but I will need to find the words length as well so this was helpful.

Comment: `len(word)` . to get the length of a string